# How to get table names dynamically with datatable and Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, datatable

I have two tables and I am using multiple datatable

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="card-box table-responsive">
            <table id="table1" class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive table-hover" data-table="tableOne">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>First name</th>
                        <th>Last name</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="card-box table-responsive">
            <table id="table2" class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive table-hover" data-table="tableTwo">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>First name</th>
                        <th>Last name</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to send a parameter that would be the idtable or the name of the table through ajax where I have the attribute for each table `data-table` .

```js
$('table.table').DataTable({
        "autoWidth": false,
        "paging": true,
        "info": true,
        "responsive": true,
        "filter": true,
        ajax: {
            url: base_url+"controller/action",
            "type": "POST",
            data: function (d) {
                d.data = "data-table"; //id_table
            }
        },
        "stateSave": true,
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
    });
```

In theory it should work like this: `d.data = $(this).attr("data-table");` of form dynamically , and its result would be for table1 = tableOne and for table2 = tableTwo, but it does not work for me :(

It works for me like this; `d.data = $('table.table').attr("data-table");` , but the first table is repeated twice `table1 = tableOne` and `table2 = tableTwe`, and that way it doesn't work for me.

Can someone help me please, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: I am not sure I have understood your question, so this is a comment not an answer. Where you use `$(this)`, that refers to the Ajax function inside the DataTable. So, from there you can get the `data-table` attribute of the enclosing `<table>` using the following: `d.data = $(this).DataTable.settings[0].nTable.getAttribute("data-table")`. My hesitation is because (a) this is ugly; and (b) I have no idea why you would want or need to do this: you already know the details of each table for which you are creating a DataTable - so can you not just hard-code the values?

Comment: thanks for your contribution, but trying it `$(this).DataTable.settings[0].nTable.getAttribute("data-table")` and it gave me the same result `table1 = tableOne` y `table2 = tableOne` :(

Comment: I am using multi datatable and I need to identify the name of each table to know what to query in the database, in order not to repeat code, I am avoiding using two Ajax methods in the `.js` files, knowing that this multi table is for that

Comment: Understood - thank you for the explanation. I am now able to recreate your problem, and I see that my suggestion does not work - but I do not know _why_ it does not work. That is odd.

Comment: still reviewing your contribution put `$(this).DataTable.settings[1].nTable.getAttribute("data-table")` and its result is: `table1 = tableTwo` y  `table2 = tableTwo`. We are on the spot to solve my question

Comment: Maybe that is because the DataTables API can refer to [multiple tables](https://datatables.net/manual/api#Multiple-tables). Not sure how that will help in your specific situation, though.